# Инициализация БД Entity framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, entity-framework

Пытаюсь создать и инициализировать базы данныз методом Code first.

```
static class Program
{
   System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new QA_Initialization());
}
```

Вот код класса QA_Initialization:

```
class QA_Initialization : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<QA_Context>
    {
        protected override void Seed(QA_Context context)
        {
            context.aUsers.Add(new AnswerBot.AUser { ChatId = 993793675, Name = "User1" });
            context.SaveChanges();
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

И QA_Context

```
class QA_Context : DbContext
    {
        public QA_Context() : base("QA_Context") 
        {  }

        // Questions Bot DB //

        public DbSet<QUsers> qUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UAnswers> uAnswers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UQuestions> uQuestions { get; set; }

        // End //

        // Answers Bot DB //

        public DbSet<AUser> aUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AAnswers> aAnswers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AQuestions> aQuestions { get; set; }

        // End //

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Questions DB //

            modelBuilder.Entity<QUsers>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<QUsers>().Property(k => k.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UQuestions>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UQuestions>().Property(k => k.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UQuestions>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UQuestions>().Property(k => k.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            // End //

            // Answers DB //

            modelBuilder.Entity<AUser>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AUser>().Property(k => k.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AQuestions>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AQuestions>().Property(k => k.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AAnswers>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AAnswers>().Property(k => k.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            // End //
        }
    }
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <contexts>
    <context type="TelegramBot.Database.QA_Context, TelegramBot">
      <databaseInitializer type="TelegramBot.Database.QA_Initialization, TelegramBot" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="QA_Context" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=QTelegramBot;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Проблема заключается в следующем: таблицы в БД не создаются. Проганял программу через откладчик, и заметил что в метод Seed класса QA_Initialization программа вообще не заходит. Как решить эту проблемму?

Comment: Проведите любую реальную операцию через контекст - инициализация отработает на первом вызове

Comment: @PashaPash, Вы имеете в виду начальную инициализацию проводить в конструкторе контекста? Но тогда проблема в другом - после каждого перезапуска программы начальные данные не перезаписываются, а просто добавляются в конец таблицы. Конечно, можно перепроверить на наличие этих данных, и если они уже есть - не добавлять, но это выглядит как-то глупо.

Comment: Нет, вы правильно все настроили, но вы не делаете ни одного реального обращения к контексту в Program. В EF ленивая инициализация - пока вы не попытаетесь вытащить из него данные (или не попытаетесь добавить) - он ничего не делает. Создайте в program контекст и сделайте context.aUsers.ToList() - и инициализация отработает.

Comment: @PashaPash, большое спасибо, всё работает!